# Problem with rowcolor in tables

Tags: tables, color, multicolumn

Please help me.
I have a problem with this table. I have other tables in my document, but `rowcolor` worked fine. Particularly, this code of my table has something wrong.
I want the header colored with gray.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow,array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Title}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{50mm}|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{20mm}|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{20mm}|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{20mm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{Gray} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Text}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{20mm}|}{\textbf{Text}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{20mm}|}{\textbf{Text}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{20mm}|}{\textbf{Text}}\\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Gray} \textbf{Descripción} & \textbf{Nº} & \textbf{Sueldo mes} & \textbf{Total Año}\\\hline
\textbf{Text} & Text & & Text\\
\textbf{Text} & Text & & Text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks, but i defined the color in the preamble. I've just change the code.

Comment: Your code works for me. May be you need an update of your tex distro.?

Comment: @HarishKumar I have a question, if I define a new row without multicolumn, it works: `\hline
\hline
\rowcolor{Gray} \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text}\\\hline
\hline`   May have something more in the code of the row where there are multicolumn commands?

Comment: It works as it is for me! More details may be needed here.

Comment: @HarishKumar I answered the question, with `rowcolor` in each cell. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people who has the same problem, this code works for me; I defined the `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rowcolor{Gray}\textbf{Text}}` for each cell, instead of define de `\rowcolor` at the beginning of the row.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Title}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{50mm}|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{20mm}|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{20mm}|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{20mm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rowcolor{Gray}\textbf{Text}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{20mm}|}{\rowcolor{Gray}\textbf{Text}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{20mm}|}{\rowcolor{Gray}\textbf{Text}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{20mm}|}{\rowcolor{Gray}\textbf{Text}}\\
\hline
\textbf{Text} & Text & & Text\\
\textbf{Text} & Text & & Text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course you mean `\cellcolor`, because `\rowcolor` there will raise an error. But the table in your question compiles perfectly for me.

Comment: @egreg Maybe, the software I use miss some update, as HarishKumar said. I work in Texpad software. Anyway, `cellcolor` also works for me.